# Hunit testing with exceptions

Tags: haskell, exception

I am writing a program to parse some xml.

I took the approach of using `MonadThrow` to take care of errors in parsing, but now when testing the fails - can't figure out how to test them. Which makes me unsure if this approach is the right one.

First of all here is a complete (non-working) example

`exception.hs`

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Test.Tasty
import Test.Tasty.HUnit

import Control.Exception (SomeException, displayException)
import Control.Monad (unless)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (MonadThrow)
import Data.Function (on)
import Text.XML (Element, parseText, def, documentRoot, elementName)
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Text.Lazy (fromStrict)

data TestElement = TestElement deriving (Show, Eq)

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain unitTests

unitTests :: TestTree
unitTests = testGroup "Unit tests"
    [ testCase "parseTxt parser goodTxt1 == Right TestElement " $
        parseTxt parser goodTxt1 @?= Right TestElement
    , testCase "parseTxt parser goodTxt2 == Right TestElement " $
        parseTxt parser goodTxt2 @?= Right TestElement
    , testCase "parseTxt parser failTxt == Left \"ElementName does not match TestElement\"" $
        parseTxt parser failTxt @?= undefined
    --hunit
    ]


parseTxt :: (Element -> Either SomeException a) -> Text -> Either SomeException a
parseTxt parser inText = documentRoot <$> (parseText def $ fromStrict inText) >>=
                         parser

parser :: MonadThrow m => Element -> m TestElement
parser elmt =
    do unless (elementName elmt == "TestElement")
         $ fail "ElementName does not match TestElement"
       {-here usually some more complicated attribute/subnode parsing happens-}
       return TestElement

failTxt :: Text
failTxt = "<ToastElement></ToastElement>"

goodTxt1 :: Text
goodTxt1 = "<TestElement />"

goodTxt2 :: Text
goodTxt2 = "<TestElement></TestElement>"

instance Eq SomeException where
    (==) = (==) `on` displayException
```

which needs `exception.cabal`

```
[...]
executable exception
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Main.hs
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
               ,       xml-conduit
               ,       exceptions
               ,       resourcet
               ,       tasty
               ,       tasty-hunit
               ,       text
```

## TL;DR

I am not sure what to put instead of the `undefined` in the last unit test and if the approach of using exceptions is right in this case.

---

There are several options I thought of:

- using `(either displayException show $ parseTxt parser failTxt) @?= undefined`
  still fails and does not yield a `Left` value
- using `assertFail` defies the purpose of having a `Either SomeException TestElement` in my opinion
- I could use a self-defined exception-type in order to match against it, but can I use fail to throw an error of my own type

I think one of the sources of my confusion is that I don't know when the error is thrown (I thought lazy evaluation would throw the error when I matched against it - which is apparently wrong).

Comment: Your approach is completely sound (in my opinion) but you have made one tiny mistake. The `fail` function comes from the `Monad` class and generally just calls `error`. `fail "" :: Either () ()` is an error, not `Left ()`. So you are not actually using the `MonadThrow` interface. You should be called `throwE` with your own exception type `throwE $ MyException "..."`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user2407038 I've been able to solve this:

defining a new datatype for the exception

```
data ParseException = TagMismatch String deriving (Typeable, Eq, Show)
```

then adjusting the imports and the following functions

```
parseTxt :: Exception e => (Element -> Either e a) -> Text -> Either SomeException a
parseTxt parser inText = documentRoot <$> (parseText def $ fromStrict inText) >>=
                         (first toException . parser)

first :: (a -> c) -> Either a b -> Either c b
first f (Left l) = Left (f l)
first _ (Right r) = Right r

parser :: MonadThrow m => Element -> m TestElement
parser elmt =
    do unless (elementName elmt == "TestElement")
         $ throwM $ TagMismatch "TestElement"
       return TestElement

unitTests :: TestTree
unitTests = testGroup "Unit tests"
    [ {-...-}
      testCase "parseTxt parser failTxt == fail" $
        (first aux $ parseTxt parser failTxt) @?= Left $ TagMismatch "TestElement"
    ]
    where aux = fromMaybe (error "converting from SomeException failed")
              . fromException
```

*Note1:* the `deriving Eq` is only necessary for the `@?=` operation in the unit tests and could be omitted for the productive version of the code.

*Note2:* Also the direct dependency on `resourcet` can be replaced by `exceptions`, which the former just reexports.

Comment: Just a short comment: you are aware that your `first` function is already defined in the `Bifunctor` instance of `Either`, right?  Just import `Data.Bifunctor` to get it.